# How to save values from a dropdownlist in my database

Tags: c#

I tried to send value from `DropDownList` to database, I don't know what's the problem here, all field in the view stored but the field that change from `EditorFor` to `DropDownList` not working.

My controller code:

```
    // GET: Trainees/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.PaymentF = new SelectList(db.Payments, "id", "payment_Name");

        ViewBag.LevelList = db.Levels;
        var model = new Trainees();
        return View(model);
    }
```

===================================================================

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Include = "Nationality,FName,SName,LastName,AcademicNumber,Level,Department,PhoneNumber,Email,Hours,HourCost,Totaly,Note,payment_Name")] Trainees trainee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            var senddata = new Trainees {  };
            db.Trainees.Add(trainee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(trainee);
}
```

==========================================================

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.payment_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-3 jumbotron">
            @Html.DropDownList("PaymentF", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.payment_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

==========================================================================

This is my database structure:

[image: This picture for my Data Base]

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Include = "Nationality,FName,SName,LastName,AcademicNumber,Level,Department,PhoneNumber,Email,Hours,HourCost,Totaly,Note,payment_Name")] Trainees trainee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

          
               
                db.Trainees.Add(trainee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(trainee);
        }

Comment: Abdullah, please note that you can edit your question (and should do that instead of adding extra information as a comment). If you have solved your issue, then you can add details of how as an answer using the box below (where it says "Your answer")

Comment: please follow Johns advice

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see in the code above your passing `null` as the second variable in the Dropdownlist which we usually pass the `data` source type `List<SelectListItem>`.please mentioned how you bind your data to the dropdownlist.

if your form post to the `action`, and your dropdownlist has a value selected then you can get the value as below

```
var itemValue = Request.Form["PaymentF"];
```